# Share components between apps using typescript and javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have 2 different apps in 2 different folders.

One is a typescript app using nextjs13 app router and the other is a react app using javascript.

Is it possible to use components from nextjs/typescript app in my react/javascript app.

Trying to access using a relative path gives me “your component is not in src/ folder ….” But i am using app router so that’s not possible. Tried other things but none of them worked out.

The only thing that worked was copying and pasting stuff but I would assume there is a much concrete way. As i would like to have benefits of typescript from my new nextjs app before I find time to move my react app.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "monorepo"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working after sometime. @Ethan answer didn't work for me (as mentioned in the comments). The same component in turbo repo works in a tsx project but not in js.

I got it working the following way:

- Create a react project with typescript.
- In your `src` folder create an `index.ts` and `components` folder.
- `index.ts`

  ```js
      export * from './components’;
  ```
- `components`:

  - `index.ts`:

    ```js
        export { default as Button } from './Button';
    ```
  - `Button`:

    - `button.ts`

      ```js
        import React, { FC } from "react";
        import './Button.css';
        import { ButtonProps } from "./Button.types";

        const Button:FC<ButtonProps> = ({type,text,onClick}) =>{
            return (
                <button type="button" className={`Button Button-${type}`} onClick={onClick}>
                    {text}
                </button>
            )
        };
        export default Button;

        // "./Button.types"
        import { MouseEventHandler } from 'react';

        export interface ButtonProps {
            type: 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'error';
            text: string;
            onClick: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;
        }
      ```
    - `index.ts`

      ```js
          export { default } from './Button'
      ```
    - in `src` folder create `tsconfig.json`, `rollup.config.js`, `

      - `tsconfig.json`

        ```json
            {
              "compilerOptions": {
                "target": "es5",
                "module": "esnext",
                "jsx": "react",
                "sourceMap": true,
                "outDir": "dist",
                "strict": true,
                "moduleResolution": "node",
                "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
                "esModuleInterop": true,
                "skipLibCheck": true,
                "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
              },
              "include": [
                "src",
                "globals.d.ts"
             ],
              "exclude": ["node_modules", "*.js", "dist"]
            }
        ```
      - `rollup.config.js`

        ```js
        import { readFileSync } from 'node:fs';
        import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
        import { nodeResolve } from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
        import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
        import eslint from "@rollup/plugin-eslint";
        import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
        import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
        import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
        const packages = JSON.parse(readFileSync(new URL('./package.json', import.meta.url)));
        export const file = (type) => `dist/index.${type}.js`;


        const overrides = {
          compilerOptions: {
            noUnusedParameters: true,
            noUnusedLocals: true,
            strictNullChecks: true,
            moduleResolution: "node",
            declaration: true,
            allowSyntheticDefaultImports: true,
          },
          useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true,
        };
        export default {
          input: "src/index.ts",
          output: [
            {
              name: packages.name,
              file: file("umd"),
              format: "umd",
              globals: {
                react: 'React',
                'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
                'styled-components': 'styled',
              },
            },
            {
              file: file("esm"),
              format: "es",
              sourcemap: "inline",
              globals: {
                globals: {
                  react: 'React',
                  'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
                  'styled-components': 'styled',
                },
              },
            },
          ],
          external: ["react", "react-dom"],
          plugins: [
            json(),
            eslint({
                throwOnError: true,
                throwOnWarning: true,
                fix: true,
                include: ['src/**/*.ts'],
                exclude: ['node_modules/**', 'lib/**', '*.js'],
            }),
            commonjs(),
            postcss({
              minimize: true
            }),
            typescript({
              tsconfigOverride: overrides,
            }),
            nodeResolve({
              extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx", ".less"],
            }),

            // terser(),
          ],
        };
        ```
      - `package.json`

        ```json
        {
          "name": "rollup-build-react",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "description": "",
          "main": "dist/index.esm.js",
          "type": "module",
          "files": [
            "dist"
          ],
          "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
          "scripts": {
            "build:ts": "tsc",
            "build": "rm -fr dist && set NODE_ENV=production&& rollup -c",
            "prepublishOnly": "npm run build"
          },
          "keywords": [],
          "author": "",
          "license": "ISC",
          "devDependencies": {
            "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^23.0.2",
            "@rollup/plugin-eslint": "^8.0.5",
            "@rollup/plugin-json": "^5.0.1",
            "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.0",
            "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
            "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.40.1",
            "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.40.1",
            "eslint": "^8.26.0",
            "postcss": "^8.4.18",
            "rollup": "^3.2.3",
            "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
            "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
            "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
            "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.34.1",
            "tslib": "^2.4.0",
            "typescript": "^4.8.4"
          },
          "peerDependencies": {
            "react": ">= 16.8.0",
            "react-dom": ">= 16.8.0"
          },
          "dependencies": {}
        }
        ```
    - afte all this, run `npm pack` in your root folder which will create a .tgz file.

Now create a new react javascript app. cd to the root folder and write `npm i {PATH_TO_BUILD_TGZ}

- This will add the following in packagejson `"rollup-build-react": "file:../rollup-build-react-1.0.0.tgz",`
- In your App.js import `import { Button } from 'rollup-build-react';` and use `<Button type="primary" text="hello" onClick={ () => null } />` .

All done.

Answer (score 1):

As @Phix said you need to use a monoerepo. There are many solutions such as NX, Learna, and TurboRepo. In this case I think Turbo is the best option since it's designed for Next.js.

[Follow this guide](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/getting-started/create-new) from the TurboRepo docs and replace the starter apps with your Next and React apps. Then move all your components to `packages/ui` and import them into all of the files you need them in. It takes some work but it's well worth it for your use case.

Comment: I tried that but I get "ERROR in ./src/.../custom.js 374:46-50
export 'Card' (imported as 'Card') was not found in 'ui' (module has no exports)". when I try to import the "tsx" component form the packages/ui folder in my react/js app. I dont see the issue with my next/typescript(web) app.

Comment: in browser 

caught Error: Cannot find module './card'
    at webpackMissingModule (styleTagTransform.js:14:1)
    at ../../packages/ui/index.tsx

Comment: Because your component should now be imported as `import someComponent from "@packages/ui/someComponent"`.

Comment: that didn’t work out. “Ui/card could not be resolved”. If i look at the sample apps it creates, it does only import from ui so “import card from “ui””. Also we export the ui library not packages/ui so that is not recognised at all

Comment: My import statement is the same as the one from the sample.